# How do I activate AnyEdit-Plugin in JBoos Tools HTML Editor?

Tags: eclipse, jboss-tools

I am using [JBoss Tools](http://tools.jboss.org/) for developing my JavaEE-applications.

There is this Eclipse-plugin [AnyEdit](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/).

This plugin brings a context-menu (as describe [here](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/anyedittools/)). Which works fine, when I open a text-file with default Eclipse "HTML Editor". But this AnyEdit' context-menu does not appear, when I open a text-file with "JBoss Tools HTML Editor". The AnyEdit-shortcuts do not work in "JBoss Tools HTML Editor", too.

Is there a way, to have AnyEdit-context in "JBoss Tools HTML Editor"?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that AnyEdit assume a bit too much about how an editor should work - that said it should actually work. I suggest you open a bug against JBoss Tools in https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBIDE and we will take a look.

Thus please test with the *latest* version of JBoss Tools for Eclipse Luna and if the problem continues open the bug and we'll look and figure out the cause.